# Spring JSP: Trouble with spring form with modelAttribute="" and path=""

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Using the modelAttribute="" tag and the path="" tag don't make sense to me when there is only one string to be passed to the controller. However, when a form has multiple textboxes, it actually does make sense to have an object model for them. This way the modelAttribute tag represents the object, i.e. "Employee", and the path tags represent the fields, i.e. "firstName", "lastName", "salary".

What do you do when you only want to pass one string though? I shouldn't have to create a "Key" class with a "key" field with getKey() and setKey() or any of that craziness just to pass a string to a controller method, right? What is the convention in this case?

If I just do `model.addAttribute("key", "")` when the page loads, I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'key' 
of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'key' is not readable or has an invalid 
getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

If I delete the modelAttribute="key" tag I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for 
bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

**JSP**

```
<form:form method="post" action="myAction" modelAttribute="key">
   <td>
       <form:input path="key" value="${myValue}"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </td>
</form:form>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleMyActionRequest(@ModelAttribute("key") String key, Model model) {

    // do stuff with key string.

    return HOME_PAGE_REDIRECT;
}
```

What is the convention for passing a single string to a controller method when a form is submitted, without having to create a new class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got this idea, but I really do not know if it can be advisable in general. After all, it's just an in line version of the process you would like to avoid. Anyway, there I go:

In you backing bean, add the string to the model like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(Locale locale, Model model) {

    Object theTempBean = new Object(){
        public String key = "blahblahblah";

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    };

    model.addAttribute("theTempBean", theTempBean);

    String viewName = "home";
    return new ModelAndView(viewName, "command", model);
}
```

The JSP should look like this:

```
    <form:form action="/myAction" modelAttribute="theTempBean">

        <form:input path="key" /> 
            <input
                type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form:form>
```

then, the the web controller's method that handles the form post, should be something like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/myAction")
public String myAction(@RequestParam("key") String param){
    logger.info(param);
    return "home";
}
```

I tested this simple example and it works as expected with Spring version 4.2.0.RELEASE and the Jetty Maven plugin version 9.3.2.v20150730.

**EDIT**

There is a bug. If you decide do this, you have to set "theTempBean" in any request (maybe it could become a `@ModelAttribute`. Again, it's just an in-line version of an extra bean class). This is the fixed action handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/myAction")
public String myAction(@RequestParam("key") String param
        , Model model){
    logger.info(param);

    Object theTempBean = new Object(){
        public String key = param;

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    };

    model.addAttribute("theTempBean", theTempBean);

    return jspViewName("home");
}
```